# Generating a Lottery Number Generator in Python

Tags: python, loops, random, while-loop, generator

I am an amateur and I need some help in my making of a lottery number generator.
I have got going a while loop where I make a variable set that variable to 0 then I tell python that while that variable is less than 6 it needs to create a random number within a range of 1,49 and I then tell it to add 1 to my variable this then creates 6 numbers within the range of 1,49 although what I need is for these numbers to be in ascending order and with no doubles, so no repeating numbers.

Comment: What code have you tried to write already? Stack Overflow questions require code of your own, and examples make it a lot clearer to us what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Are you able to write the basic version (not dealing with ascending order and doubles)?  It sounds as if you are describing the steps quite logically so it is just a matter of writing each step.  Can you get a single random number?  If you can do any of the steps then let us know what you have done and what you are stuck with.

Answer (score 7):

Are you allowed to use Python's `random` library? If so, this is trivial.

The [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) function takes a population (in your case the numbers 1 to 49), and number of samples to draw (in your case 6). Then you can use the [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function to get the numbers in ascending order.

```
>>> import random
>>> sorted(random.sample(range(1,50), 6))
[2, 9, 20, 30, 33, 46]
```

A few more just to show that it is indeed random

```
>>> sorted(random.sample(range(1,50), 6))
[12, 22, 24, 28, 34, 39]
>>> sorted(random.sample(range(1,50), 6))
[1, 11, 20, 21, 24, 37]
>>> sorted(random.sample(range(1,50), 6))
[2, 4, 7, 21, 32, 48]
>>> sorted(random.sample(range(1,50), 6))
[10, 20, 26, 41, 44, 49]
>>> sorted(random.sample(range(1,50), 6))
[4, 5, 6, 21, 33, 41]
```